# How to change the color of a bar of a chart in google sheets when a cell is populated for the bar's row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that I'm working to test a small dashboard on.  My goal is to show the time some units are out of manufacturing and heading to the finishing department for polish, coloring, etc.  What I want to achieve is to have the color of the bar for the associated row to change color when one of the cells is populated.  In my googling, I've managed to find bits and pieces, but I don't know enough JavaScript to be able to take the things I have found and use them, let alone understand them for the most part.

Here is the test sheet I've been working on:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b09CKYbrxe7riS6mXx6OfQk4TrQcBcghU4_YvuIt1lA/edit?usp=sharing

Basically, I want for the D Column to change the row's bar on the second tab of the spreadsheet.

I do understand it would be an onEdit(e) function and an IF statement to make it work.  As well, a second function for changing the bars, but I don't know what that would be.

Comment: Do you have any code currently that is generating/modifying the chart?

Comment: I currently have a sorting event that automatically sorts the rows based on Column C then A.